# Is there a way to open a file on Mac OS through C#?

Tags: c#, macos

If I have a path to a file, eg. an existing application on my mac, How can I use C# to open that file?

For example, here's a path to terminal on Mac OS
`/Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app/Contents/MacOS/Terminal`

I tried using this code below by compiling it to an exe through csc, then using mono to execute it.

```
namespace democonsole
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            
           System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("/Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app/Contents/MacOS/Terminal");

        }
    }
}
```

Terminal returned an error of

````
Unhandled Exception:
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): Cannot find the specified file
  at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithShellExecuteEx (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo) [0x00102] in <6de7aa624f1544329fc30bc179f3b197>:0 
  at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start () [0x00032] in <6de7aa624f1544329fc30bc179f3b197>:0 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
  at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo) [0x0001b] in <6de7aa624f1544329fc30bc179f3b197>:0 
  at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start (System.String fileName) [0x00006] in <6de7aa624f1544329fc30bc179f3b197>:0 
  at democonsole.Program.Main (System.String[] args) [0x0000c] in <1d59817ec01e4193b472af562e50f6f2>:0 
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): Cannot find the specified file
  at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithShellExecuteEx (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo) [0x00102] in <6de7aa624f1544329fc30bc179f3b197>:0 
  at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start () [0x00032] in <6de7aa624f1544329fc30bc179f3b197>:0 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
  at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo) [0x0001b] in <6de7aa624f1544329fc30bc179f3b197>:0 
  at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start (System.String fileName) [0x00006] in <6de7aa624f1544329fc30bc179f3b197>:0 
  at democonsole.Program.Main (System.String[] args) [0x0000c] in <1d59817ec01e4193b472af562e50f6f2>:0 ```
````

Comment: Though I have changed the path, @HansPassant I am still getting the same error above.

Comment: Use a code to show you the actual path.  You have an expectation of access to `/`, and it may be that you are actually in a container.  It may or may not be reasonable to assume direct access to `/` is offered, depending on macOS version and system integrity protection settings.